Spherical isoperimetric inequality: condition for strict inequality (i.e. "$>$"), and lower bound proof?
I am reading the Wikipedia article "Spherical measure". It defines the usual arclength metric $\rho_n$ and the spherical measure $\sigma^n$ on the sphere $S^{n}$. It moves on to say:
For $A \subset S^{n}$ a Borel set and $B \subset S^{n}$ a $\rho_n$-ball (i.e. $B$ is a "spherical cap") with $\sigma^n(A)=\sigma^n(B)$ , and for any $r > 0$, the following inequality holds
$$ \sigma ^{n}(A_{r})\ \geq\ \sigma ^{n}(B_{r})$$
where $A_r$ denotes the "inflation" or "blowup" of $A$ by $r$, i.e.
$$ A_{r}:=\{x\in S^{n}\mid \rho _{n}(x,A)\leq r\}$$
and similarly for $B_r$. [In the definition of $A$ and $B$, the Wikipedia article uses $S^{n-1}$ but I think this is an error; I think it should be $S^n$]
In particular, if $\sigma^n(A) ≥ ⁠1/2$⁠ and $n ≥ 2$, then we have a lower bound
$$\sigma^n(A_r)\ \geq\ 1 -\sqrt{π/8}\ \exp(−(N − 1)r^2/2)$$
I have two questions on this and would be grateful for any help:

Question No.1:
In case $A$ is not a spherical cap, does it then turn into a strict inequality
$\sigma ^{n}(A_{r})\ >\ \sigma ^{n}(B_{r})$ ?

That would be my intuition. Because even if we assume $A$ is spherical cap plus one separate point (i.e. $\sigma^n(A)=\sigma^n(B)$ still holds), then the blow-up or inflation of that one point will have measure $>0$. Hence the inequality should be strict in that case.

Question No.2: Where does the lower bound for $\sigma^n(A_r)$ come from if $\sigma^n(A) ≥ ⁠1/2$?

I could not quite deduce that. I have looked up the article of Talagrand called "A New Look at Independence" and the book "Concentration Inequalities" from Boucheron, Lugosi, and Massart; but like in the Wikipedia article, the steps are not detailed there either.
